# Para que serve o método setRequestHeader no AJAX puro em modo POST?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Para que serve e qual a importância deste tradicional método `setRequestHeader` do AJAX puro quando são feitas requisições do tipo POST pelo cliente para uma aplicação PHP no servidor? Sempre sou obrigada a usa-lo com o valor `"Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` sem saber ao certo sua real função. Também gostaria de saber as falhas de segurança já conhecidas pela comunidade que podem ser causadas no servidor caso o PHP eventualmente receba um cabeçalho com valor diferente deste que, para mim que sou leiga, é um valor padrão. Sua utilização é obrigatória?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`XHR().setRequestHeader`** serve para definir um cabeçalho na lista de cabeçalhos da requisição. Quando você chama ele dessa maneira:

```js
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

você está definindo o tipo de conteúdo que vai atribuir na requisição do método **`"post"`** ou **`"put"`**, lá no primeiro parâmetro de **`XHR().send`**. O tipo de conteúdo **`"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`** só indica que o conteúdo está no formato de parâmetros de URL, por exemplo: `"?param=1&etc=2"`

**Cabeçalhos sempre são usados em requisições, nunca há risco de segurança para o servidor.**

Verifique essa [página](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_campos_de_cabe%C3%A7alho_HTTP), ela lista cabeçalhos que podem ser definidos em uma requisição. Observação: nem todos cabeçalhos podemos definir programaticamente com o método **`XHR().setRequestHeader`**.

Não há *risco* de segurança em *relação* à cabeçalhos. Não existe essa coisa de não enviar cabeçalhos, e além disso eles não podem afetar o servidor.

Para obter mais informações ainda, há uma especificação sobre o `XMLHttpRequest` [aqui](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#author-request-headers).

O que pode afetar o servidor depende de suas ações.

Comment: Praticamente respondida a pergunta, mas com exceção da segurança. Existem falhas conhecidas pela comunidade e como poder proteger o `callback` de receber os dados enviados pelo AJAX com uma lista de cabeçalhos configurada errada ou propositalmente trocada? Afinal, tudo que vem do lado dos usuários deverá sempre ser muito bem verificado. Como confiar? Obrigada =)

Comment: @IngridFarabulini Não adianta tentar proteger o callback, você tem que proteger o seu código ao lado do servidor. Com ajuda dos dados que vem ao lado do cliente, você pode detectar facilmente alguma manipulação de dados ao lado do servidor com uma condição, e com isso você impede alguém de fazer uma determinada ação em um banco de dados, por exemplo, e pode responder o JavaScript com alguma mensagem informando que houve uma falha à fazer tal ação.

Comment: @IngridFarabulini Sempre que você quer segurança para fazer algo ao lado do servidor através do JavaScript já tenha uma ação determinada nos parâmetros do URL ou no conteúdo de postagem, não tente expor dados importantes e manipulação à eles para o cliente.

Comment: @IngridFarabulini Lembrando: mesclar Strings ao lado do servidor em uma requisição do PDO, por exemplo, `SELECT...`, pode ser perigoso se você não cobrir/verificar essa String porque ela pode conter uma ação e ser interpretada, provavelmente, creio que a String pode ser codificada, e assim não acontece nada (porém esqueci sobre tudo). Infelizmente já faz um bom tempo que eu não uso essas APIs do PHP, até porque não precisei muito por enquanto, e agora esqueci das síntaxes usadas em requisições de banco de dados

Comment: Entendo suas palavras, mas ainda me sinto insegura com essa configuração de cabeçalhos. Mesmo não sabendo se tal falha de segurança por eles existem, acredito que seja a pessoa mal intencionada um bom caminho a ser explorado, ainda mais que basicamente é pelo lado do cliente que vamos dizer ao servidor como estão configurados os dados que estão sendo enviados, algo que facilmente poderá ser modificado até mesmo por pessoas leigas como eu e então injetados códigos que comprometam.

Comment: @IngridFarabulini Apenas você pode dar a possibilidade de fazer um código que pode ser facilmente manipulado, algo que possa permitir alguém modificar um banco de dados ou configurações do servidor, modificar arquivos, etc... Se você quer que isso não aconteça, você precisa codificar suas Strings de acordo com o que elas serão mescladas (sempre importante na síntaxe de fazer uma ação no banco de dados com uma String, por exemplo, **`INSERT...`**), até porque lá pode ser juntada uma ação extra, então é isso... se você codificar uma string, ela não será interpretada.

Comment: @IngridFarabulini Um exemplo de codificação é usando base64, `base64_encode(string)`, e se você quiser ler essa string depois de receber ela do banco de dados, `base64_decode(string)`

Comment: @IngridFarabulini Como sempre: também nunca deixe o client-side fazer ações que acessem o interior do PHP; já tenha ações determinadas através de parâmetros.

Comment: @IngridFarabulini É importante limitar determinadas ações com condições, porém eu não sei que tipo de problema de segurança você está tendo, sendo assim é difícil ajudar à resolvê-lo.

Comment: Não estou tendo nenhum problema... mas não confio nesses cabeçalhos. Obrigada por estar tentando ajudar =)

Comment: @IngridFarabulini Eu entendo, mas na verdade o navegador sempre tem que mandar cabeçalhos para uma requisição, se eles fossem perigosos, muitos sites já teriam sido manipulados. Os cabeçalhos que podem ser definidos por nós não causam problemas de segurança ao lado do servidor.